# App/GUI for matching up list items?

Tags: data-mapping, data-manipulation

I am migrating data from one database schema to another. I have to match up fields from the old to the new.

I'd like to have a simple app or GUI interface where I have a list of the tables and fields schema on the left and the other schema on the right. I'd like to have lines connecting one item on the left to another on the right. I'd like an easy drag-and-drop functionality to associate one to the other.

I understand that the fields will not match 1:1 in all cases, but this is all I need/want to get started.

I could do this in a text editor or a spreadsheet but I'd like a UI that's a little more robust. It gets difficult making space to insert a new item on one side without knocking off the alignment for left/right relationships below.

Is there some desktop or web app that will help me with this?